# setTimeout not always working in Greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey, settimeout

I've found a lot of similar problems but none equal and no right solution. This is a very strange issue.

I have a simple Greasemonkey script to test the issue:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        testdiddio
// @namespace   http://userscripts.org/users/useridnumber
// @include     https://www.google.it/
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==


function wait(){
    console.info("wait");
    setTimeout(wait,1000);
}

console.info("start");
wait();
```

This is the output from firebug:

```
start
wait
wait
wait
wait
```

The wait() function is called 4 times then stops. If I set the Timeout to 100ms the call seems works for at least 10/15 seconds then stops.

I'm using:
Firefox 12.0
Greasemonkey 0.9.19

Comment: maybe because Greasemonkey script stops running when web page is fully loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Greasemonkey 0.9.19.
A feature was added to allow `setTimeout()` to work even when a page's JS was disabled and it introduced some complications (Issues [1549](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1549), [1552](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1549), and [1553](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1549), etc.).

It should be resolved shortly in release 0.9.20, or revert to version 0.9.18.

Comment: Thanks I have just installed version 0.9.18 and everything's fine. You saved my day.

Comment: This seemed to be happening to me with 0.9.20 as well, just to let you know - reverted to 0.9.18 and that seems to have fixed the issue. I'd be happy to try something out for testing if there are any questions (like if 0.9.20 was actually SUPPOSED to have fixed the issue).

Comment: @CodeJockey, as best we can tell, 0.9.20 *did* fix the issue.  If you have code that proves otherwise, consider filing a [bug report](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues), or possibly a new SO question.