# GM_log and other GM functions don't work in Greasemonkey scripts

Tags: logging, firebug, greasemonkey

I have created a "Hello World" Greasemonkey script in Firefox which contains only one line of code:

```
GM_log("Hello World");
```

This did not seem to function, at least it did not produce any  output in my firebug console.
The same with other GM_... functions like GM_wait

When I replaced:

```
GM_log("Hello World");
```

with:

```
alert("Hello World")
```

it worked (so the script headers are not the problem).

I have also set the following `about:config` options to true:

- `javascript.options.showInConsole`
- `extensions.firebug.showChromeErrors`
- `extensions.firebug.showChromeMessages`

Is there some other setting to change for GM_... functions to work in Greasemonkey scripts?

Do I have to change other firebug settings for GM_log messages to show in the firebug console?

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this is a new special *Metadata Block imperative*: **@grant**, added in GM 1.0.
If you need GM_log to work, you have to add this line into your script Metadata Block:
`"// @grant GM_log"`
, otherwise it will not work.
You can read about this feature at http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant.

Answer (score 3):

Where did you get `GM_wait`?  That is not [a GM function](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Category:API_Reference); some people just name their ad-hoc functions that. Note that [GM version 0.9.19 broke a lot of timing functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553751/331508), but this was fixed in version 0.9.20.

As for `GM_log()`, that works but it doesn't always put its message in a sensible location.  On later versions of Greasemonkey, `GM_log()` writes to Firefox's Error Console -- which you can open by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.
But, [as Comentarist said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10623970/331508), there is no good reason to use `GM_log` anymore.  It's of limited functionality and does not port well.

All the good browsers now support `console.log()` natively (No Firebug required), but on Firefox, this also tends [to output to Firefox's Error Console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10135917/331508).

To use [Firebug's excellent logging functions](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) (well worth a look), you currently must use `unsafeWindow` like so:

```
unsafeWindow.console.clear ();
unsafeWindow.console.log ("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you forget about GM_log() and use:

```
console.log('hello world');
```

http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_log

Like it says "since GM_log will only display a single string at a time, users with Firebug installed may prefer to use console.log instead."

But about your question, I couldn't say why.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with console.log. I also replaced GM_wait with an "ordinary" javascript function. Strange, that other GM functions still work without problems (GM_xmlhttpRequest).